# Избыточно ли такое построение архитектуры?

Tags: python, python-3.x, архитектура, декоратор

У меня есть функции, которые принимают входные данные, и вызывают другую функцию, передавая эти данные.

```
def add_document_with_input_value():
    dir_number = input("Введите номер полки")
    document_type = input("Введите тип документа")
    document_number = input("Введите номер документа")
    document_name = input("Введите владельца документа")
    return add_document(dir_number, document_type, document_number, document_name)
```

И мне показалось, что такие инпуты смотрятся слишком объёмно и как то не очень красиво.
Я решил написать функцию, которая будет запрашивать нужное количество запросов на ввод данных

```
def get_value_input_count(count: int = 1):
    if count > 0:
        value_count = [input(f"Введите значение №{i + 1}\n") for i in range(count)]
        return value_count[:count]
    raise ValueError("Введите число больше 0")
```

Но здесь наткнулся на проблему, что я таким образом не понимаю, что именно сейчас вводить: тип документа или его номер (т.е., придётся как то помнить, в каком порядке вводить значения).
Для решения этой проблемы, я решил создать словарь, ключом которого будет имя функции, а значение - список с текстом, необходимым для ввода.

```
prompt = {
    "add_document_with_input_value": ["\n(№1) Введите номер полки", "\n(№2) Введите тип документа", "\n(№3) Введите номер документа", "\n(№4) Введите владельца документа"],
}
```

И потом декоратор, который и будет выводить мне подсказки, что и в каком порядке вводить.

```
def get_prompt_entry_value(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        name_func = func.__name__
        get_prompt = prompt.get(name_func)
        if get_prompt:
            print(*(i for i in get_prompt))
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

И по итогу, получается такая функция:

```
@get_prompt_entry_value
def add_document_with_input_value():
    dir_number, document_type, document_number, document_name = get_value_input_count(4)
    return add_document(dir_number, document_type, document_number, document_name)
```

И собственно сам вопрос: рационально ли было так выкручиваться, или же лучше было оставить исходный вариант, т.к. более ясно, что к чему и делается ли так вообще?

Comment: наверное в вашем случае стоит обратиться к истокам.к пеп. Красивое лучше, чем уродливое.
Явное лучше, чем неявное.
Простое лучше, чем сложное.
Сложное лучше, чем запутанное.
Читаемость имеет значение.

Comment: @execution Тогда уж сворачивать до вида `return add_document(*get_value_input_count(4))`. Да и параметр `4` можно не передавать, а взять длину списка из `prompt`.

Comment: @GrAnd да, я понимаю, я просто только переделал этот вариант, и не занимался оптимизацией и т.д., не узнав, надо ли оно. Но спасибо большое за совет!

Comment: @GrAnd, да и плюс к тому, думал так более явно видно, что именно передаю в аргументы

Answer (score 4):

По-моему, вы усложняете себе жизнь на ровном месте. Декораторы зачем-то... Как по мне, решение "в лоб" получается и компактно, и понятно:

```
def input_values_with_prompt(prompts: list) -> list :
    return [input(f"Введите {prompt}: ") for prompt in prompts]

def add_document_with_input_value():
    prompts = ["номер полки", "тип документа", "номер документа", "владельца документа"]
    return add_document(*input_values_with_prompt(prompts))
```

Comment: да, но смысл и был в том, чтобы вынести подсказки в отдельное место)

Comment: Ну так вынесите список `prompts`. Этому же ничего не мешает.

Comment: так это нужно будет для каждой функции выносить отдельно и т.д., а мой вариант автоматизирован для этого, в одном месте собраны все подсказки, и он исходя из имени функции - сам подберёт нужное количество входных данных и список подсказок

Answer (score 3):

Отвечая на вопрос в заголовке: в данном случае такая архитектура, очевидно, избыточна, но тем не менее поразбираться в работе тех же декораторов может быть интересно и полезно.

---

По вашему коду. У вас не очень логично работает: сначала выводится 4 запроса что ввести, потом 4 раза запрашивает. И декоратор неявно полагается на глобальную переменную prompts, что делает его негибким. Тут имеет смысл сделать декоратор, в который передается список запросов, декоратор сам все запрашивает, и раскладывает по аргументам функции, например:

```
def input_arguments_with_prompts(*prompts):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            args = list(args)
            for prompt in prompts:
                args.append(input(prompt))
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator


@input_arguments_with_prompts(
    "Введите номер полки: ",
    "Введите тип документа: ",
    "Введите номер документа: ",
    "Введите владельца документа: "
)
def add_document_with_input_value(dir_number, document_type, document_number, document_name):
    print(dir_number, document_type, document_number, document_name)


add_document_with_input_value()
```

Пример ввода/вывода:

```
Введите номер полки: 2
Введите тип документа: 12
Введите номер документа: 4
Введите владельца документа: sdfsdf
2 12 4 sdfsdf
```

---

Можно заморочиться, и добавить, чтобы декоратор понимал аннотации типа у аргументов декорируемой функции: например, если если у аргумента указан тип `int` то конвертировать аргумент в соответствующий тип. Набросок кода:

```
import inspect


def input_arguments_with_prompts(*prompts):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            parameters = inspect.signature(func).parameters
            # в parameters будет объект вида OrderedDict([('dir_number', <Parameter "dir_number: int">), ('document_type', <Parameter "document_type">), ('document_number', <Parameter "document_number: int">), ('document_name', <Parameter "document_name: str">)])
            for prompt, (name, parameter) in zip(prompts, parameters.items()):
                while True:
                    value = input(prompt)
                    if parameter.annotation is inspect._empty:
                        converted_value = value
                        break
                    else:
                        try:
                            converted_value = parameter.annotation(value)
                        except ValueError:
                            print(f"Некорректное значение: {value}")
                            print("Повторите ввод")
                        else:
                            break

                kwargs[name] = converted_value
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator


@input_arguments_with_prompts(
    "Введите номер полки: ",
    "Введите тип документа: ",
    "Введите номер документа: ",
    "Введите владельца документа: "
)
def add_document_with_input_value(dir_number: int, document_type, document_number: int, document_name: str):
    print(dir_number, document_type, document_number, document_name)


add_document_with_input_value()
```

Пример ввода-вывода:

```
Введите номер полки: wefer
Некорректное значение: wefer
Повторите ввод
Введите номер полки: 12
Введите тип документа: erger
Введите номер документа: 1
Введите владельца документа: fgerg
12 erger 1 fgerg
```

Вместо простых типов можно указывать функции, которые будут валидировать значения (например, что оно больше нуля), кидать `ValueError` в случае ошибки, и возвращать значение в случае успеха (в идеале вместо функций должны быть callable классы отнаследованные от [`typing.NewType(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html?highlight=typing#newtype), чтобы линтеры типа mypy не ругались). Пример:

```
def larger_than_0(value):
    value = int(value)
    if value <= 0:
        raise ValueError

    return value


@input_arguments_with_prompts(
    "Введите номер полки: ",
    "Введите тип документа: ",
    "Введите номер документа: ",
    "Введите владельца документа: "
)
def add_document_with_input_value(dir_number: larger_than_0, document_type: str, document_number: larger_than_0, document_name: str):
    print(dir_number, document_type, document_number, document_name)



add_document_with_input_value()
```

Похожим образом (через обработку аннотаций типов) работают такие библиотеки, как [fastapi](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi) и [typer](https://github.com/tiangolo/typer).

Comment: В итоге получается, что по записи оно почти и не отличается от исходного варианта автора. Зато мороки... :)

Comment: Ну да, конкретно для этой задачи это конечно overkill. Но в целом кто-то же заморачивается, пишет всякие typer, click и т.д., хотя есть же проверенные временем argparse или getopt )

Comment: Ну и был императивный стиль, а стал как бы декларативный)

Comment: Если оформлять это в библиотеку для публичного доступа, то можно заморочиться с красивым API и запрятать всё "под капот". Но если это только в рамках одной задачи, то это лишняя трата времени. IMHO. Хотя, конечно, каждый волен выбирать тот стиль, который ему больше подходит. Я вот с ассемблера начинал. Там не больно разгуляешься с красотами в коде. :)

Comment: @insolor, безумно благодарен за такой обширный и очень полезный ответ, много чему можно научиться. Пока разбираю по кусочкам Ваш код, так все же однозначного ответа не получил: все же лучше явно в фукнции получить input()?

Comment: @execution, как вам удобнее, так и делайте. Для вашей задачи достаточно просто 4 раза input вызвать. Если бы было намного большее количество вводов, тогда имело бы смысл что-то улучшать. Но при большом вводе уже удобнее было бы загружать, например, табличный документ (csv, excel и т.д.), а не вбивать вручную.

Comment: @insolor, да, я понимаю что и 4 раз инпута достаточно было, но, как то захотелось более красивого и изящного кода что ли..) Ещё раз большое спасибо за помощь!